# Error in Creating Index using Java High Level Rest Client in Opensearch behind a VPC

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch

I am trying to create an index in the Opensearch domain which is behind a VPC. I have created an EC2 Instance and installed NGINX on it so that it can act as a reverse proxy to forward the request to VPC Opensearch domain.

When i test the code with Postman i see a "405 Not Allowed" in the logs. To ensure if the code works fine i have tested it against the Public Endpoint of a different Opensearch domain and i can see the index gets created without any issues.

Below is my NGINX configuration:

```
server {
listen      80;
listen      443 ssl;
server_name ec2xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com;

ssl_certificate        /etc/nginx/cert.crt;
ssl_certificate_key    /etc/nginx/cert.key;
ssl_protocols          TLSv1.2;
ssl_ciphers            HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

location ~ ^/$ {
    proxy_pass https://vpc-xxx-instance.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_method PUT;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header content-type "application/json";
    proxy_set_header   Host $host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto: https;


}
```

Error:

org.elasticsearch.client.ResponseException: method [PUT], host [ec2xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:443], URI [/index-test-vpc?master_timeout=30s&timeout=30s], status line [HTTP/1.1 405 Not Allowed]

```
<html>
<head><title>405 Not Allowed</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>405 Not Allowed</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.20.0</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the location parameter i specified a specific request parameter("/test") and called the cURL below and it created the index. Ensure the Security Group has both http and https added.

```
location ~ ^/test/(.+)$ {
    proxy_pass https://vpc-xxx-instance.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com/$1;
}
```

> curl --location --request PUT
> 'https://ec2xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com/test/index-test-vpc' 
> --data-raw ''